# Toast notification disappears after few seconds, how to hold until taking any action on display?

Tags: powershell, toast

I'm trying to make a small PowerShell program to display a toast notification after log on.
I'd like the custom toast notification will stay there until user closes it. But but it disappears quickly. (about 5 seconds)

How can I do that ?

Script:

```
Import-Module BurntToast

$button = New-BTButton -Dismiss -Content "OK"

New-BurntToastNotification -Text 'Yoooo, this is a toast notification... from PowerShell!' -Button $button
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast), couldn't you just use the `-SnoozeAndDismiss` option?

Comment: No I will use dismiss function. NOT Snooze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works, using a [variety of cmdlets](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast/tree/main/Help) from the [`BurntToast`](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast) module, as of v0.8.5:

```bash
Submit-BTNotification -Content (
  New-BTContent -Scenario IncomingCall `
                -Audio (New-BTAudio -Silent) `
                -Visual (
                  New-BTVisual -BindingGeneric (
                    New-BTBinding -Children (New-BTText -Content 'Testing...') `
                                  -AppLogoOverride (
                                    New-BTImage -AppLogoOverride -Crop Circle -Source $env:windir\System32\wpcatltoast.png
                                  )
                  )  
                ) 
)
```

- `-Scenario IncomingCall` is the key to making the notification "sticky".
- `New-BTAudio -Silent` suppresses the sound that accompanies the notification when it first appears.

  - If you don't use this, you'll get two *ringing* sounds in quick succession, instead of the single sound that is used by default.
  - Unfortunately, explicitly selecting the default sound with `New-BTAudio -Source ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Default` is *not* effective, as `-Scenario IncomingCall` seems to override it (the same goes for attempts to select any other sound).

Note:

- No button for dismissal is created, because a close icon is available by default.

  - A custom logo is displayed, which is shown to the left of the text.
  - Note that you seemingly can *not* customize the application name and logo in the *title* of the notification, which, when called from PowerShell, invariably shows the PowerShell logo and the title "Windows PowerShell" (even when calling from *PowerShell (Core)*).
- While [this Microsoft Q&A post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187209/how-make-toast-notification-keep-display-until-use) suggests that adding a button *implicitly* makes a notification sticky, at least in the context of the `BurntToast` module that is *not* true, as you've experienced.
- The [docs for the underlying .NET APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.toastscenario) suggest that the `Reminder` and `Alarm` scenario values too make a notification sticky, but at least in the context of the `BurntToast` module that is *not* true; in fact, the latter seems to *ignore* these `-Scenario` values as of v0.8.5 and uses a default notification (same as `-Scenario Default`).
- While there is a way to modify the *default display duration* (which is `5` seconds) via a *registry value*, as shown below, this requires a *logoff or reboot* to take effect, which means that you can *not* change it *temporarily, in-session*, and it will apply to *all*  notifications (that do not *explicitly* control their display duration).

  ```bash
  # Set the default display duration to 300 seconds == 5 minutes.
  # Requires logoff or reboot to take effect.
  Set-ItemPropert 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Accessibility' MessageDuration 300
  ```

Comment: thannks btw, That defeats the purpose of a toast notification...use the alarm sound for 25 seconds, the incoming call method for ~5mins, or switch to something else that shows a new Windows form.

https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast/discussions/97

Comment: lastly ,  I want to add company logo too. How can I do that ?

Comment: @Arbelac: Re logo: please see my update. Re the linked discussion: As far as I can tell, an `IncomingCall` notification does _not_ disappear after 5 minutes. I've left one up for many hours. Thus, the solution above should work. You could argue that it isn't what toast notifications were designed for, yet the _docs_ suggest that `Reminder` (as well as `Alarm`) _is_ designed to be sticky (they aren't at least when invoked via the `BurntToast` module - not sure about direct API use).